# How do we run multiple functions concurrently in Scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, concurrency, bigdata

This is a scala code I'm trying to write for processing a function multiple times concurrently with two different parameters. However, I notice that the functions are being executed one by one and not both at same time.

```
class Method1 extends Thread {
  override def run(): Unit ={
    println("Hello, Current running is Thread No. " + Thread.currentThread().getName )
    Function("Parameter 1")
    Function("Parameter 2")
  }
}
object Obj extends App {
    for (x <- 1 to 4){
      val th1 = new Method1()
      th1.setName(x.toString)
      th1.start()
    }
}
val a = Array("Justanormalarray")
Obj.main(a)
```

How to achieve this? Sorry for being dumb but all tutorials I seen only explains a very basic level that multithreading can be achieved by extending thread class or by using runnable interface, but doesn't seem to clear this up (i.e. how to actually execute multiple stuff at same time)

Comment: You should read about Scala's `Future`s if you plan to do this in Scala. There's (almost never) need to work directly with `Thread` in Scala.

Comment: In your case, I believe the code is running concurrently 4 times but it's so fast that you might see the output as sequential. Put some `Thread.sleep` in `Method1#run` after the `println` should give you a better insight.

Comment: Re, "I notice that the functions are being executed one by one..." How can you tell that? Does `Function(...)` print something or do something that tells you whether or not the calls are overlapped? The four "Hello,..." messages _must_ come out one-by-one because the `println()` function (actually, Java's `System.out.println()`) uses a lock to prevent the output of different println() calls from being interleaved.